# WordPress navigation menu

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress

I currently have a nav menu that is built with the following,

```
<?php 
            if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
                wp_page_menu('show_home=1&exclude=214&exclude_tree=80');
            } else {
                wp_page_menu('show_home=1&exclude=214');
            }
        ?>
```

My problem is that I have some BuddyPress pages that I need add to parent that is created by WordPress, basically I have a parent that is called 'Member Content'

That Member Content has children like, 'Surveys', 'Documents' but I also want Forums, Groups, Members from my BuddyPress install to be children of the member content also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddypress has several pages you are going to have to call. You'll need to include the pages manually, so it would look something like this:

```
<?php 
        if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
            wp_page_menu('show_home=1&exclude=214&exclude_tree=80');
        } else {
            wp_page_menu('show_home=1&exclude=214');
```

class="selected">
                    //" title="">

```
        <li<?php if ( bp_is_page( BP_MEMBERS_SLUG ) || bp_is_member() ) : ?> class="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>/<?php echo BP_MEMBERS_SLUG ?>/" title="<?php _e( 'Members', 'buddypress' ) ?>"><?php _e( 'Members', 'buddypress' ) ?></a>
        </li>

        <?php if ( bp_is_active( 'groups' ) ) : ?>
            <li<?php if ( bp_is_page( BP_GROUPS_SLUG ) || bp_is_group() ) : ?> class="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>/<?php echo BP_GROUPS_SLUG ?>/" title="<?php _e( 'Groups', 'buddypress' ) ?>"><?php _e( 'Groups', 'buddypress' ) ?></a>
            </li>

            <?php if ( bp_is_active( 'forums' ) && bp_is_active( 'groups' ) && ( function_exists( 'bp_forums_is_installed_correctly' ) && !(int) get_site_option( 'bp-disable-forum-directory' ) ) && bp_forums_is_installed_correctly() ) : ?>
                <li<?php if ( bp_is_page( BP_FORUMS_SLUG ) ) : ?> class="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                    <a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>/<?php echo BP_FORUMS_SLUG ?>/" title="<?php _e( 'Forums', 'buddypress' ) ?>"><?php _e( 'Forums', 'buddypress' ) ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( bp_is_active( 'blogs' ) && bp_core_is_multisite() ) : ?>
            <li<?php if ( bp_is_page( BP_BLOGS_SLUG ) ) : ?> class="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>/<?php echo BP_BLOGS_SLUG ?>/" title="<?php _e( 'Blogs', 'buddypress' ) ?>"><?php _e( 'Blogs', 'buddypress' ) ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>


        }
    ?>
```